# Parsing the Xml file which dont have any child nodes

Tags: android, android-xml, android-parser

I am new in android development, I want to parse one particular xml file using Dom Parser. The xml structure is something like this.

```
<Images>
   <image link="a.tgcdn.net/images/products/zoom/e554_android_plush_robot.jpg"/>
   <image link="a.tgcdn.net/images/products/zoom/e554_android_plush_robot.jpg"/>
   <image link="http://cdn.androidpolice.com/wp-content/themes/ap1/images/android1.png"/>
   <image link="http://cdn.androidpolice.com/wp-content/themes/ap1/images/android1.png"/>
   <image link="http://cdn.androidpolice.com/wp-content/themes/ap1/images/android1.png"/>
</Images>
```

I want to add those web links in a arraylist.
suggest me some way out for it.. Even any link or tutorials related to this will be helpful. Thanks.

here is full code..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    String xmlurl       = "--url of xml---";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<String> mImageLink = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(xmlurl);
            XMLParser   parser  =   new XMLParser();
            String      xml     = parser.getXMLfromUrl(url);
            Document    doc     = parser.getDomElement(xml);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc1 = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc1.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc1.getElementsByTagName("photo");

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Element websiteElement = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
                nodeList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();              
                mImageLink.add(websiteElement.getAttribute("link"));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<mImageLink.size();i++){
            Log.d("Photo link --- " + i,mImageLink.get(i));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is homework: [Android - DOM parsing example](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Android+dom+parsing+example)

Comment: @NitinBathija See my answer may be it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Use below code to Parse above XML file using DOM Parser.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> mImageLink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            mImageLink = new ArrayList<String>();

            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.temp);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(is));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("image");

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;

                mImageLink.add(fstElmnt.getAttribute("link"));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

And see below link for more information.

[XML Parsing Using DOM Parser](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-domparser)

Comment: Its not showing any output.. just a blank screen.. I have added INTERNET permission also in manifest.

Comment: I just followed the same tutorial which u suggested after changing the require changes which u mentioned here above, and even in that tutorial also one of the user have same problem if u can see the comments below that code i.e on same link of yours.

Comment: @NitinBathija If you are looking for solution then post your code.

Comment: I have posted my code.. check that out and xml file having urls like this.. http://a.tgcdn.net/images/products/zoom/e554_android_plush_robot.jpg

Comment: @NitinBathija Where is your XML file URL?

Comment: I have updated the xml in my question. the xml its exactly like that only on my url.

Answer (score 0):

use [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/) library and it's SAXReader.

```
    InputStream is = FileUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("file.xml");

    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    org.dom4j.Document doc = reader.read(is);
    is.close();
    Element content = doc.getRootElement();  //this will return the root element in your xml file
    List<Element> methodEls = content.elements("element"); // this will retun List of all Elements with name "element"
```

for DOM parsing you can use the same lib's [DOMReader](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/io/DOMReader.html)